# Get the last row of result set in Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query in `laravel`

```
$listings = DB::select('select auction.*, product.* from auction as auction inner join
            product as product on auction.productID=product.id where auction.sold=0 and auction.endDate != NOW() order by auction.created_at desc limit 10');
```

Now I want to get the `id` on the last row or the 10th row of the result set `$listings`. How could I do that?
I couldn't use this kind of code `$lastID = Auction::orderby('created_at','desc')->first()` because it fetches the last row from the table and not from the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this to get the last record from the result set:

```
$listings = DB::select('select auction.*, ...  limit 10');

$last = end($listings);
```

Now get the `id`:

```
$id = $last->id;
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for quick and accurate answer! :D